# OCR Libraries/Tools for TIFF analysis using Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, ocr, hadoop2

I am currently working on a requirement to analyze the images and extract text and contents for further analysis. The images need to be processed using Hadoop due to huge volume. I am looking for libraries that can fit well in MapReduce paradigm as well as give most flawless conversion possible. I am looking for not only open source but any commercial libraries that can fit into this requirement. Can the experts on this exchange guide me on what options I should choose for further analysis and prototyping?

I am currently analyzing Tesseract library but will like to see any better candidates for this requirement.